# CSS classes get overridden by a different class despite using !important keyword

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

My goal is to resize modal form. Despite defining classes and setting them, they get overridden by another class.

tsx file :

```
import styles from '../../../../../../../kit/components/modals/Modal/Modal.module.scss';

<ModalForm
      modalProps={{
        isOpen: isProposalModalOpen,
        title: `Proposal reason for ${candidate.firstName} ${candidate.lastName}`,
        hasMaxWidth: false,
        modalForm: true,
        onClose: onModalClose,
        className: {
          base: styles.customModalSize,
          afterOpen: 'modalAfterOpen',
          beforeClose: 'modalBeforeClose',
        },
        overlayClassName: {
          base: styles.customModalForm,
          afterOpen: 'modalAfterOpen',
          beforeClose: 'modalBeforeClose',
        },  
      }}
      content={
        <div
          style={{
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            alignItems: 'center',
            width: '100%',
          }}
        >
          <textarea
            id="proposalComment"
            name="proposalComment"
            value={reason}
            onChange={(e) => setReason(e.target.value)}
            placeholder={`Comment here`}
            style={{
              width: '90%',
              height: '300px',
              border: '1px solid #ccc',
              borderRadius: '4px',
              padding: '8px',
              boxSizing: 'border-box',
              resize: 'vertical',
            }}
          />
        </div>
      }
      contentSubmit={false ? '' : 'Propose'}
      formProps={{
        onSubmit: () => {
          handleProposeClick();
        },
      }}
    />
```

.scss file which I am importing into .tsx:

```
   .container {
  --modal-width: 510px;
  --modal-height: 190px;
  --modal-padding-bottom: 49px;
  --max-modal-width: 720px;
  --modal-space-h: var(--space-m);
  --modal-border-radius: 5px;

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: var(--modal-width);
  min-height: var(--modal-height);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: var(--bright-light);
  border-radius: var(--modal-border-radius);
  outline: none;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}



.customOverlayClass {
}

.modalAfterOpen {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
}

.modalBeforeClose {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.95);
  transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
}

.customTmCandidateActionsModal {
  --modal-width: 110px;
  --modal-height: 100px;
}

.customModalForm {
  --modal-width: 210px !important;
  --modal-height: 100px !important;
}

.customModalSize {
  max-width: 300px !important; 
  --modal-width: 210px !important;
  --modal-height: 100px !important;
}
```

Modal form size doesn't change. It will change only if I change --modal-width in container.
tried to put console.log(styles) after import and it definitely loads custom classes.

I don't want to change anything inside a .container because it will affect other modal forms. Is there any other way?

Comment: Using `!important` on css custom vars only affects the variable resolution, but not the eventual property value. See: https://css-tricks.com/the-surprising-behavior-of-important-in-css-custom-property-values/